# Failed to pull Docker image Beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Every ElasticBeanstalk deploy with eb_deployer fails with this error:

```
[2015-02-11T15:02:31.551Z] INFO  [6528]  - [CMD- Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-02-11T15:02:33.280Z] INFO  [6528]  - [CMD- Startup/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh
Pulling repository foo/bar
2015/02/11 15:02:33 Error: image foo/bar not found
Failed to pull Docker image foo/bar:staging: Pulling repository foo/bar
2015/02/11 15:02:33 Error: image foo/bar not found. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
  at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:81:in `sh'
  from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor.rb:15:in `sh'
  from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:63:in `execute!'
```

The Docker image definitely exists, and can be pulled locally using the same tag.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be an authentication failure with the remote docker api

Comment: How did you fix it?